# Shiny R Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, csv, plot, shiny

The thing is I want to develop a interface that I can read and plot the current table from csv file (7by3 with headers) and input 3 new figures(one column(category) data into a csv file table) to update the table. Then overwrite the CSV file and plot the new updated table.
Everything is alright with showing current table.

BUT, the problem comes...
I tried the my codes manually(using real file path rather than variable file path) and separately over Rstudio command window and it is all right. However, I got error "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" when I press "Enter" to overwrite csv file and show the new table.
The codes below is the ui.R server.R global.R files for my interface.
Please help me with this error.

```
# ui.R
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
fluidPage(
selectInput(
    inputId = "fileSelect",
    label = "Select the file",
    choices = c("dataA", "dataB", "dataC",
            "dataD", "dataE"
    )
  ),
  selectInput(
    inputId = "cateSelect",
    label = "Select the category",
    choices = c("A", "B", "C", "D",
            "E", "F", "G"
    )
  ),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h3("View the current table and Input values "),
      actionButton(
        inputId = "showTable",
        label = "Show current table"
      ),
      numericInput(
        inputId = "low",
        label = "Input the Low value",
        value = 5 
      ),
      numericInput(
        inputId = "moderate",
        label = "Input the Median value",
        value = 5
      ),
      numericInput(
        inputId = "high",
        label = "Input the High value",
        value = 5
       ),
      actionButton(
        inputId = "inputValue",
        label = "Enter"
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("currentTable"),
      dataTableOutput("updatedTable")
    )
  )
)

# server.R
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
function(input, output) {
  tempTable <- reactive(
    {
      if(input$fileSelect==lookUpFile[1]){
        tableFile = tableA
      }
      if(input$fileSelect==lookUpFile[2]){
        tableFile = tableB
      }
      if(input$fileSelect==lookUpFile[3]){
        tableFile = tableC
      }
      if(input$fileSelect==lookUpFile[4]){
        tableFile = tableD
      }
      if(input$fileSelect==lookUpFile[5]){
        tableFile = tableE
      }
      tableFile
    }
  )

  tablePlot <- eventReactive(
    input$showTable,
    {
      tempTable()
    }
  )
  output$currentTable <- renderDataTable(
    tablePlot()
  )
  cate <- reactive(
    {
      if(input$cateSelect==lookUpCate[1]){
        cate <-lookUpCate[1]
      }
      if(input$cateSelect==lookUpCate[2]){
        cate <-lookUpCate[2]
      }
      if(input$cateSelect==lookUpCate[3]){
        cate <-lookUpCate[3]
      }
      if(input$cateSelect==lookUpCate[4]){
        cate <-lookUpCate[4]
      }
      if(input$cateSelect==lookUpCate[5]){
        cate <-lookUpCate[5]
      }
      if(input$cateSelect==lookUpCate[6]){
        cate <-lookUpCate[6]
      }
      if(input$cateSelect==lookUpCate[7]){
        cate <-lookUpCate[7]
      }
      tableFile[,cate]
    }
  )
  tablePath <- reactive(
    {
      if(input$fileSelect==lookUpFile[1]){
        tableFile = "tableA"
      }
      if(input$fileSelect==lookUpFile[2]){
        tableFile = "tableB"
      }
      if(input$fileSelect==lookUpFile[3]){
        tableFile = "tableC"
      }
      if(input$fileSelect==lookUpFile[4]){
        tableFile = "tableD"
      }
      if(input$fileSelect==lookUpFile[5]){
        tableFile = "tableE"
      }
      tableFile
    }
  )

  updated <- eventReactive(
    input$inputValue,
    {
      tempTable[,cate] <- c(input$low, input$moderate, input$high)
      fileName = paste(tablePath,".csv",sep='')
      write.csv(
        tempTable,
        file = fileName,
        col.names = T,
        row.names = F
      )
      updated = read.csv(fileName,header = T, sep = ",")
    }
  )
  output$updatedTable <- renderDataTable(
    updated()
  )
}

# global.R
library(shiny)
# Loading data file.
tableA = read.csv("~R/Rdata/tableA.csv",header = T, sep = ",")
tableB = read.csv("~R/Rdata/tableB.csv",header = T, sep = ",")
tableC = read.csv("~R/Rdata/tableC.csv",header = T, sep = ",")
tableD = read.csv("~R/Rdata/tableD.csv",header = T, sep = ",")
tableE = read.csv("~R/Rdata/tableE.csv",header = T, sep = ",")
lookUpFile <- c("dataA","dataB","dataC","dataD","dataE")
lookUpCate <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G")
```

Comment: This means you're using extract i.e. [ ], to subset, on a function, rather than a data object (i.e. a vector). It's my favourite obscure error message (a function is a closure).

Comment: So how can I solve this error?
Many thanks for your reply.
Best wishes.

Comment: Search for instances of "[" in your code and see if any of them are functions rather than data. My guess is: tempTable[,cate] - tempTable is a function.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. It is the line where the error is coming as I checked. The thing is I want to rewrite one column of data. What can I do rather than using this tempTable function?
Best wishes,

Comment: Or should I use another way to store the tempTable. Sorry that I am a beginner to Shiny and R. So I am still a bit confused about the way it stores data.

Comment: The whole definition of the reactive `cate` is confusing. It would not have access to `tableFile`, which appears to be a temporary variable used only in `tempTable` and in `tablePath` (for two different reasons it seems). Then later to use the reactives `tempTable` and `cate` you would need to call them as functions, e.g., `tempTable()[,cate()]`.

Comment: Hi Brian, Many thanks for your comment. But I tried with your tempTable()[,cate()] got a error "invalid left side of assignment". The thing is I want to let user to store their input into the selected location. That is why I have the tempTable which stands for which file and cate for which column they want to input. Please help me with it. Thank you. Or should I change the way to store the file name? Thank you